# How to GROUP and choose lowest value in SQL and associated column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

This question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885879/how-to-group-and-choose-lowest-value-in-sql) earlier question (not asked by me).

I have a table consisting of these fields:

```
 id  |   date_from  | date_to      |   price  | priceName
 --------------------------------------------------------
 CK1     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       800      low
 CK1     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       1200     medium
 CK2     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       1400     high
 CK2     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       1800     very high
 CK2     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       2200     extortionate
```

How do I create a SQL select that groups the results by ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO and picks the lowest value from price *and the priceName that is associated with the lowest price*?

So the result would be

```
 CK1     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       800     low
 CK2     22-12-2012   29-12-2012       1400    high
```

From the previous question I can do:

```
select id, date_from, date_to, min(price)
from table
group by id, date_from, date_to
```

How do I extend this to only select the priceName that matches the min(price)? Grouping by priceName won't work because it does not constrain to the min(price).

Comment: Does your table have some sort of row_id primary key or it is compound key (id, date_from, date_to, price)? You can wrap your query in CTE and get missing praceName based on that key in main query. `WITH cte AS (SELECT uniqueId, ...) SELECT * FROM table_name t JOIN cte c ON  t.uniqueId = c.uniqueId`

Comment: It is a compound key: id, date_from, date_to (not price).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery.

```
Select Table.id,Date_from,date_to,MinPrice,PriceName
from
   (select id, min(price) as MinPrice
   from table
   group by id) t1
INNER JOIN table ON t1.id=table.id and t1.MinPrice=table.Price
Group by id,Date_from,date_to,MinPrice,PriceName
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be one of the simplest answers and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT id, date_from, date_to, price, priceName
FROM   (SELECT id, date_from, date_to, price, priceName,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date_from, date_to
                            ORDER BY price ASC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select t.*,t1.priceName from (
select id, date_from, date_to, min(price)
from table
group by id, date_from, date_to) t
join table t1 on t.id =t1.id 
and t.date_from =t1.date_from  
and t.date_to =t1.date_to
and t.price =t1.price
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE:

```
WITH cte (id, date_from, date_to, minprice) AS (
     SELECT id, date_from, date_to, [minprice] = min(price)
     FROM table_name
     GROUP BY id, date_from, date_to)
SELECT
    c.id, c.date_from, c.date_to, c.[minprice], t.priceName 
FROM table_name t 
JOIN cte c 
ON t.id = c.id
    AND t.date_from = c.date_to
    AND t.data_to = c.date_to
```